# MPSCNNConvolution crash in construction

Tags: ios, swift, conv-neural-network

I am currently replacing the deprecated call

```
  let layer = MPSCNNConvolution(device: device,
                                convolutionDescriptor: desc,
                                kernelWeights: weightsData.pointer,
                                biasTerms: biasData?.pointer,
                                flags: .none)
```

into

```
  let data = DataSource(name, kernel.0, kernel.1, inChannels, outChannels)

  let layer = MPSCNNConvolution(device: device, weights: data)
```

Therefore I have created a DataSource implementing the MPSCNNConvolutionDataSource protocol which receives the parameters at construction and implements all required functions. The constructed Datasource seems to be OK when I inspect it in the debugger.

However I get SIGABRT when I construct the MPSCCNConvolution. The system does not output anything, it just crashes silently.

Anybody had similar experiences ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault: My DataSource.load() was returning false all the time. That lead to the crash. The rest of the code was OK.